# Approximating Geodesics in a half edge DS, how can I refine my mesh to get good approximations

Tags: mathematics, computational-geometry, geometry, subdivision, tesselation

I implemented Djikstra's shortest path algorithm to approximate Geodesics on arbitrary meshes. Djikstra's works, but I noticed a problem inherent to the discretization of my meshes.

Consider the following figure squence:

[image]
[image]
[image]

...

[image]

This is my current refinement algorithm which is the easiest/standard face subdivision. Now consider the approximation of a geodesic in 2 points:

[image]

The blue point is where I think the actual geodesic intersects that edge, which is quite far from where the approximated geodesic passes. However that path ISN'T wrong.

Consider a square grid. The distance between any 2 points in the grid is the manhattan distance  |x| + |y|.

So as far as Djikstra's is concerned, a path that goes all the way down and then to the left has the same length as a path that goes diagonally in a staircase pattern. Refining the mesh won't change the distance either. In other words, the limit of the shortest path found by Djikstra in a regular square grid as the size of the squares goes to 0 is NOT the straigtht line connecting 2 points.

Now the actual question, does anyone know of a way to subdivide my surface that is fairly straightforward but will actually converge to the geodesic?

Comment: Intriguing problem! If I am not mistaken, the situation is even worse than you expected in the sense that any path going through the blue point should be a little bit longer than the path you found with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: The analytic path should be shorter, but the approximation might be longer

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant to say. I think you found the (unique) shortest path between the two red points, among all paths that move along the triangles' edges.

Comment: In this specific case there's just one, but in general there might be multiple, including infinite.

Comment: How can there be infinitely many shortest paths?

Comment: @Chris Consider the sphere, take the 2 poles, every single great circle connecting the 2 points is a geodesic path. Thus, there are infinitely many.

Different shapes have different properties but most shapes have at least one pair of points that are connected by an infinite amount of geodesics.

Comment: Modify your search to use the Euclidean distance between vertices (on the same face), it's possibly not as efficient but should give the correct results.

Comment: @lightxbulb My faces are triangles, so it's technically already doing that.

Comment: From my understanding if that was the case you would be getting the blue point. You already mentioned you use manhattan distance. I suggest using Euclidean distance.

Comment: It really is a problem directly related to the discretization. No matter how much you refine the triangles with the above subdivision strategy, you'll never get convergence to the true geodesic in the above example (using the euclidean distance). This is very unintuitive and makes the problem quite interesting imo

Comment: The explanation regarding the square grid is a bit misleading since it does not apply to the example given in the pictures.

Comment: @lightxbulb The easiest way to understand the problem is perhaps, look at the last image and try to come up with a shorter path in the generated grid than the green path.

You will notice that you can't find a shorter one. Then imagine you do one further subdivision step, you will notice that a newly detected path on that more refined grid is actually pretty close to the one on the last image, despite there being 3x more edges to pick from.

Comment: I think that if the method was using Euclidean distance then you would get a "staircase" path, so even without a further refinement you will be a lot closer to the blue point. I'll elaborate. You say: "The distance between any 2 points in the grid is the manhattan distance |x| + |y|" - this doesn't need to be the case. You can measure the Euclidean distance between the two points. Then you would get the path that you want for your geodesics. To be sure, measure the distance in the continuous space, not on the graph.

Comment: @Makogan Wouldn't the path on the refined grid be exactly the same as the one you have now, as long as you keep the red points at the same position? Maybe it would be helpful if you added more pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the problem here is the discretization/subdivision of the mesh. If your mesh was made of quadrilaterals instead of triangles, the obvious subdivision strategy would be to split each quadliteral into four equally sized smaller quadliterals:

$\hspace{2cm}$
[image]
$\hspace{2cm}$
[image]

For any two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, Dijkstra's algorithm would yield sets of shortest paths between these points $P_1$ and $P_2$. The more you refine the discretization with this subdivision strategy, the more shortest paths you'll find between the two points. However, intuitively it is clear that for every subdivision level $l\in\mathbb{N}$ you could pick one of these shortest paths $p_l$ such that the sequence $(p_l)_{l\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to the actual geodesic between $P_1$ and $P_2$ (with respect to some norm that has to be specified, for example the supremum norm).

Unfortunately, the same is not true for the standard subdivision strategy of splitting a triangle into four smaller triangles, which you have proven with your example. I believe that, at its core, the problem is that there is no way to reach the center of the triangle with a straight line from each of its edges. This can be achieved by splitting a triangle in each subdivision step into 6 smaller triangles like this:

$\hspace{2cm}$
[image]
$\hspace{2cm}$
[image]

I do not have a proof that this subdivision is more useful to compute geodesics with Dijkstra's algorithm, but it seems quite likely to me. I would be very interested to see what your results look like with this subdivision strategy! However, no matter what you do, in the end you may or may not end up with sets of shortest paths instead of a single shortest path. In this case you will need some kind of heuristic or additional algorithm to decide which path resembles the true geodesic most closely.

Comment: I think you have it wrong, given the square subdivision you gave, a refinement of that will not converge towards the geodesic, because the distance between 2 points remains constant. I explained that on my original question : p

Comment: Your triangle scheme has given me and Idea, so I will test that out and get back to you

Comment: This is why I wrote *sets* of shortest paths. You always need to make sure you calculate all shortest paths and not just one random path. Then you indeed get convergence as I explained above.

Comment: I am going to have to ask another question here before I get back to you

Comment: This is not what I ended up doing but it;s probably better, my solution was just to start randomly splitting edges (I just did it this way because it;s easier in my current implementation) but this will probably work too.

Comment: I am sure that there are many different solutions. A randomized subdivision scheme sounds very interesting too. If you were worried about using too much space and just wanted to find one particular geodesic, adaptive subdivision strategies would also be quite useful.